# Got JAVA exception: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown KeySpec type

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7, birt

I have built a JAVA web application which uses SOAP to fetch data from an external database server. This works fine until a few days ago. Now, the connection to the database server is terminated while establishing them.

In my JAVA log file, I found the following sequence of exceptions:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.throwSSLException(Handshaker.java:1260)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:283)
    ...
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown KeySpec type: java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
```

Maybe the provider of the database server has changed their SSL certificate and got another CA chain. 
I noticed that the intermediate CA use SHA384withRSA as signature algorithm. (see [COMODO, Domain Validation (SHA-2)](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/979/108/domain-validation-sha-2)).

So, what can I do to to make my system running again?
Please ask, if you need further information.

Remark: The same SOAP request from a Windows 7 client works fine. There I noticed, that the Windows 7 client uses TLSv1.2 to establish the SSL connection. The Linux system of my server (see below) uses TLSv1 ,

The configuration of my Java WebServer:

- Debian Wheezy
- Java: OpenJDK 1.7.0u111
- Tomcat 7.0.28

  - https connector uses JSSE with sslProtocol="TLS"
- BIRT Runtime V4.5.0

  - DTP V1.12.0
  - org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws V1.2.6

Thanks
  Friedbert

Comment: You will need to post your code please

Comment: It´s difficult to add this part of code - because this error occurs within the BIRT framework.
I used a "Web Service Data Source" within a BIRT report to fetch the data from the SOAP enabled database server. Thus, the code is public available at the [Eclipse project](https://eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php). (DTP V1.12.0, org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws V1.2.6).

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Apparently, the configuration of the tomcat connector did no longer match current security standards.

I had set up the system 2 years ago. But the security requirements have increased in the meantime.

Now I took a recent appliance from turnkey, compared the settings and found a few differences:

```
JAVA: java.security
    security.provider.10=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/lib/security/nss.cfg
Tomcat7: server.xml /Connector
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
    server="Secret" URIEncoding="UTF-8" (may be, these does not matter)
```

With these changes, my system works again!